# How to execute GRANT statements to a remote database in Postgres?

Tags: database, postgresql

I would like to automate the action of the grant for a given user (myuser) to all the databases within a Postgres instance (from the **Postgres** base/user). My first attempt was to make the following script:

```
select dblink_exec ('dbname = mibase host = IP user = usersuport password = xxx',
    'GRANT SELECT on all tables in schema public to myuser;');
```

But I get a message saying that I can not execute those types of statements, I have tried using the `EXEC` with the same results, I have seen examples but I have only found for cases of `update`, `delete` and `insert`, there is also no `create`.

Any idea would be very helpful.

Thank you.

Comment: If you use `psql` to run that script, you could simply use `\c mibase` to connect to a different database

Comment: But I want to automate the GRANT to all the databases.